# How to display local time with PHP

Tags: php, timezone

Our server is set to GMT time so the hour does not keep jumping around in spring and autumn. However, during summer time, it is annoying that all the times are displayed an hour out.

How do I get and display the time, taking into account the local timezone in PHP (especially when the server thinks the local timezone is GMT).

or, How do I know if an area is using "summer time" at the moment?

or, How do I display a GMT time stamp or a different timezone?

Comment: When you say local: local to whom? The server? Every user? Just you?

Comment: Local to the the user (which is the same for all users, but isn't the same as the zone the server is on)

Comment: To avoid confusion, Summer Time is the same as Daylight Saving Time here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think I may have found the answer I need...

```
date_default_timezone_set()
// Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script
```

The PHP manual entry is here:- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 4):

You could add this line in PHP:

```
putenv("TZ=US/Eastern");
```

And every subsequent call to time()/date() will give you the time in your time zone.

[List of time zones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

This code will display the current time in the Eastern time zone (US):

```
putenv("TZ=US/Eastern");
date("h:i:s")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to offset GMT

Comment: Can you? How do you do this? You can use it to find out if daylight saving time is on, or what the timezone is, but I can't see how to adjust the timezone using this function...

Comment: You should add some sample on how to use your solution, it would improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to display local time is to use JavaScript:

```
<?php

// Get unix time from database
$seconds = .....;

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showLocalTime()
        {
            var seconds = <?=$seconds;?>;
            var date = new Date(seconds*1000);
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
            var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
            var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(minutes.length-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(seconds.length-2);

            document.getElementById("local_time").innerHTML = "Local Time: " + formattedTime;
        }
  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="showLocalTime()">
    <h2 id="local_time"> Local Time: </h2>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're assuming that JavaScript is available, and that it's desired.

Answer (score -3):

get the date/time and first check to see if the month (split on dashes if its a DATETIME field) is a 'summer month', or a month that will cause the time to be an hour out.

If so, convert it to a unix timestamp.  Then, add (or minus, whichever way it is out) 60 * 60 (60 mins) to the timestamp and convert into a human readable format.

Problem solved!

Comment: summer time does not switch on and off on month boundaries. You may know "summer time", as "daylight saving time".

Comment: There are built-in functions for this! Hacking your own Daylight Saving Time (and this is a nasty hack) is how things get broken down the road.